# Modify variables from an anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, anonymous-function

I'm trying to simply get a response from a jQuery $.get() call, and store it to a variable. It's proving to be much more difficult than I would have thought. Here is my code:

```
var response;
    $.get(("action.php?action=addFolder&folderName=" + input),  
        function(data, status){
             response = data
        }
    );
return response;
```

But response is always undefined or null. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because ajax is async. This means the ajaxcall is still doing its thing, and you are allready returning 'response'.

If you need 'response' for something (which I kinda asume), do something with it in the oncomplete of the ajaxcall. The function you use in the get is the function that gets trigger oncomplete.

> To clarify async a bit more for those who dont know what I mean*:
>
> You create the variable 'response'. After that the ajax gets started.
>   After that you return it.   The important thing in that list, is that
>   it gets returned after the ajax STARTS. If the ajax would take 5
>   seconds, the variable will have it's value after 5 seconds.

**this is simplefied*